# FBML page in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hello I want to integrate a welcome page of my website to facebook. How can I do that?
any body knows the solution please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the Application "Static FBML" on Facebook. This is an application made by facebook team itself for exactly this purpose. You will be able to put simple HTML content on a TAB of your fan/business page.

[Check google for tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=tutorial%20facebook%20pages%20with%20static%20fbml%20application)